# Have a subclassed UIButton interface with other UIView

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a subclass `MyUIButton` of `UIButton` in order to override `touchesMoved` to manage 3D touch.

Now I want that touches interact with another `UIView` on my page but I am struggling to find the proper way of doing so.

Had I not subclassed a class, I would have created a `@IBAction` in the `UIViewController` and have the outlets talk to each other. Now that I can't use the `@IBAction` I need to find a way to make my `MyUIButton` talk to the `UIViewController`, or at least outlets from it, and pointing at it from the `MyUIButton` object sounds like a bad idea.

What is the proper approach?

Comment: by derived you mean what? subclass?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit to clarify

Comment: I am contemplating doing the following: create a protocol for all the ways `MyUIButton` can interface with the other `UIView`, having my `UIViewController` implement that protocol, having a `var` delegate object that is initialized to the `UIViewController` at load. Is it the right approach? It does not seem so different from having `MyUIButton` point at the `UIViewController` but there may be fundamental advantages.

Comment: "I have created a subclass MyUIButton of UIButton in order to override touchesMoved to manage 3D touch" In my opinion, it would be better to use [UIPreviewInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipreviewinteraction). The effect is exactly the same but now you're using the expected API. The view controller is the delegate and the problem is solved. Basically, think of UIPreviewInteraction as a gesture recognizer for 3D touch.

Comment: @MadEchet You can always create an `IBOutlet` of subclassed `UIButton` there is no problem doing that just you need to do `#import "MyUIButton.h"` where you are attaching your IBOutlet.

Comment: @iphonic he's using Swift not objective-C, so there is no need of an import. Only thing I think he needs to do is : **1)** create an IBOutlet from his code, but use a the MyButton subclass, and then **2)** drag from that IBOutlet of his code to the one in his storyboard. || I think the sequence is important, because if you drag from storyboard straight into your code, it would create it from a vanilla IBOutlet and then changing it could be problematic.

Comment: @iphonic, I have been creating the outlet just fine indeed. The "problem" I have is that I can not create a `@IBAction` that is triggered when the user touches the `UIButton` or the touch is updated (the default touch down/up events don't include force information). The documentation I could find suggests subclassing the button, which means that the code sits in the subclass, not in the `UIViewController`, which means that it has not natural reference to the `UIViewController` (unlike with the `@IBAction` that creates a natural connection between the event and the view controller).

Comment: @matt, thanks for the suggestion, I did not know about UIPreviewInteraction, I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: @Honey, I can create the outlet but I am not sure how it is solving my problem. If the overridden touch events sits in the subclass, an outlet in the view controller is not aware of the events (see above my comment on default `@IBAction` available for actions). So the touch action activates some code in the subclass, not in the controller. The only way I found to tie it back to the controller was to include a delegate in the subclass and initialize it to the view controller. Then the subclass is aware of the controller and the connection can be made when the event happens.

Comment: @MadEchet Very simple example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/61f0c753a080040e4a74b912e6c18dd97fe8bcaa/bk2ch05p208forceTouchGesture/ForceTouchGesture/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks @matt, I may be wrong but I think this does not allow you to retrieve the force of the touch, there is a `didUpdatePreviewTransition` parameter in the delegate method that allows you to know how far in the transition you are but it is different to getting the force of the touch isn't it?

Comment: @MadEchet The force is rewritten as a number between 0 and 1 and is handed to you. Look closely at the code; I'm continually applying a transform in proportion to the strength of the touch. (You might have an easier time visualizing this if you actually run the example.)

Comment: Do you know what happens if the user presses all the way to full force and then releases a little? does the progress go down? (too bad I don't have a 3d touch device to test it today). The documentation on it is very slim and I'm not sure I want to make my app iOS 10 only either so I may stick to the old way. Thanks for all the insights!